# renaming file error?

Tags: elisp

I have a function to compress my pdf file using pdftk:

```
(defun compresspdf (filename)
  (interactive)
  (let ((tmpfile (concat filename "~")))
    (start-process-shell-command "pdftk" nil
    (format "pdftk %s cat output %s compress dont_ask"
        filename tmpfile))
    (rename-file tmpfile filename t)))
```

It compresses the file and saves it as the same name with `~` appended. However, at the point where it's supposed to rename the file, it gives me an error:
`let: Renaming: No such file or directory, /pathtofile/mypdf.pdf~, /pathtofile/mypdf.pdf`, though clearly, both of these files exist. I can separately evaluate rename-file afterwards and it works fine. Maybe it's trying to rename the `~` file before it's actually created? In that case, how can I make it wait until the process is finished? (and possibly check for errors?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As opposed to using `'start-process-shell-command`, which just spawns the process, so the rename happens before the `tmpfile` is created.  Try using `'shell-command`, like so:

```
(defun compresspdf (filename)
  (interactive)
  (let ((tmpfile (concat filename "~")))
    (with-temp-buffer 
      (shell-command (format "pdftk %s cat output %s compress dont_ask"
                             filename tmpfile)
                     (current-buffer)
                     (current-buffer)))
    (rename-file tmpfile filename t)))
```

The call to `'shell-command` will finish after the process is done (compression is complete).

Comment: Ah, so I can use the temp-buffer to check for errors too - great stuff!